# R suppressWarnings() not working with httr / curl

Tags: r, warnings, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to suppress a warning in R.

```
suppressWarnings(httr::GET("localhost:8080/does_not_exist"))
```

returns an error message

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

I have also tried

```
suppressMessages(httr::GET("localhost:8080/does_not_exist"))
invisible(capture.output(httr::GET("localhost:8080/does_not_exist")))
```

but I still get the same error message.

Comment: I think you are trying to suppress an error rather than a warning in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to suppress an error rather than a warning in here.  If you really don't want to see an error, you could wrap your function into `try()` and set the `silent` argument to `TRUE`. Something like this:

```
try("a" + 1, silent = T) #returns nothing
```

However, generally speaking I would advice not to do something like this, because error messages are useful rather than redundant.

Comment: While I usually agree with keeping error messages, this example is going in my own error checking function, and I want my code to respond to the error rather than stopping